# Make a part of site white

Tags: html, css

I have this registration form I am setting up and I've set the page's background to grey. I want the area in the center, where you're supposed to fill in the info, to be white. How should I do this?

I've included a picture of how the site looks now, the white part should cover the text and all the boxes. [image]

My css code for background:

```
body{
background-color:#D2D7D3;
 background-size:1500px 1000px;
z-index:0
position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: Please include your HTML code, you could put a div and put the contents of your form in there, then style the form with a width, height and background-color as #fff

Comment: in your CSS: form {background: white;}

Answer (score 1):

This is something you could do, wrap your form contents in a div and style the div around it.

This will create the white part you want behind the form.

**Example Form**

```
<div class="form-container">
 <form>
  <label for="email"> Email </label>
  <input type="text" name="email"></input>

  <label for="password"> Password </label>
  <input type="text" name="password"></input>

  <button type="submit"> Register </button>
 </form>
</div>
```

**In your CSS**

```
.form-container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```